Native-Base (2.13.0) Icon Issue
"In React Native, using the Native-base package (version 2.13.0), every component is showing an error saying 'ios-checkmark is not a valid icon name for the family ionicons.' The new Ionicons use the name 'checkmark,' but the old Ionicons are not rendering. Can anyone help?"
Try to solve this issue for display icon

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
